# Anti-aliased line and text with WebGL

Tags: javascript, vector-graphics, pixel-graphics, opengl

I have requirement to draw anti-aliased line and text in WebGL (canvas 2D). I checked [pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js) and that seems very promising. But pixi.js has many other things that I don't need. Is pixi.js is modular? Can I take some module or compile it to my requirement only?

Here are my basic requirements:

**Line:**

- Draw line with anti-aliased line
- line thickness
- line cap and join

**Text:**

- Anti-aliased Text
- Draw text along the curved line

So looking for helper lightweight JavaScript module similar to [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/samples/) for WebGL.

Comment: I am exploring [stackgl](http://stack.gl/), seems modular but not clear if it will solve my problem.